# Remove Info Button from MapBox Map

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mapbox

I created a MapBox map and added it into my iOS App. But it shows this blue detail Icon (info button) see image:

[image]

Is there a way to remove this icon?

It would be very nice!

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://www.mapbox.com/help/attribution/) when using Mapbox maps you must provide attribution.

> All uses of Mapbox’s custom maps and data must attribute both Mapbox
>   and the appropriate data providers. Mapbox’s custom design is
>   copyrighted and our data sources require attribution. This requirement
>   extends to all plan levels.

When using the iOS Mapbox SDK the info icon is automatically added:

> If you use a different Mapbox SDK library, like Mapbox.js or Mapbox
>   Mobile, the necessary attribution will be automatically included in
>   the bottom right corner of the map.

That said, here is how you can control the [attribution button](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.3.4/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(py)attributionButton) if you want to change the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can hide the icon using alpha.

```
let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
mapView.attributionButton.alpha = 0
```

But you should read this for Attribution detail here
https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/#attribution

You must comply with the licensing terms of any map data in your application, including Mapbox Streets or other Mapbox maps if used. A small attribution control will be displayed on the map view automatically. ***The attribution control may be moved or removed as necessary, so long as the required attribution is reasonably provided in your app.***

If you remove the attribution control, you must provide your users with an alternative way to opt out of Mapbox Telemetry.

Answer (score 1):

```
<MapboxGL.MapView style={styles.map} logoEnabled={false}  attributionEnabled={false} styleURL={MapboxGL.StyleURL.Street} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the answer for the 2023 version:

```
mapView = MapView(frame: view.bounds, mapInitOptions: myMapInitOptions)
mapView.ornaments.logoView.isHidden = true
mapView.ornaments.attributionButton.isHidden = true
```